# Subquery in MongoDB to retrieve course details

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, correlated-subquery

I have two documents:

```
db.COURSE.insertMany([
                {"Course_name" : "Intro to Computer Science",
                "Course_number": "CS1310",
                "Credit_hours" :  4,
                "Department"   : "CS"
                },
                {"Course_name" : "Data Structures",
                "Course_number": "CS3320",
                "Credit_hours" :  4,
                "Department"   : "CS"
                },
                {"Course_name" : "Discrete Mathematics",
                "Course_number": "MATH2410",
                "Credit_hours" :  3,
                "Department"   : "MATH"
                },
                {"Course_name" : "Database",
                "Course_number": "CS3380",
                "Credit_hours" :  3,
                "Department"   : "CS"
                }
])
```

```
db.PREREQUISITE.insertMany([
                            {
                            "Course_number":"CS3380",
                            "Prerequisite_number":["CS3320","MATH2410"]
                            },
                            {
                            "Course_number":"CS3320",
                            "Prerequisite_number":"CS1310"
                            }
])
```

I wanted to query to retrieve the course_name of the prerequisites of the “Database”
course.

How can we use subquery in Mongo DB??

Comment: Please post whatever you tried, your research, problem or debugging details.

Comment: check [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: db.PREREQUISITE.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "COURSE",
            localField: "Course_number",
            foreignField: "Course_number",
            as: "data"
        }
        
    },
 
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "PREREQUISITE",
            localField: "data.Course_number",
            foreignField: "Course_number",
            as: "CSE"
        }
    },
   {
        $match: {
           "data.Course_name": "Database",
           $in : ["CSE.Course_number"]
        } 
    },
])

Comment: I have joined the tables using aggregate, IN the $match section of IN statement i need to pass the course courses which I am getting , but it is in an array

Comment: @turivishal could you please help me how to pass this array to my match condition

Comment: Please improve your question with more details, like the expected result and whatever you have tried.